# C++/CLI System.AccessViolationException when calling unmanaged function in managed class

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a native callback function in C++, let's say something like this:

```
void ::CallbackFunction(void)
{
  // Do nothing
}
```

Now I have another native function:

```
void ::SomeNativeFunction(void)
{
  m_callback = std::tr1::bind(&::CallbackFunction, m_Tcy); // save in m_callback | m_Tcy is the class where CallbackFunction exists
  m_Tcy->SomeManagedFunction(m_callback);
}
```

Alright, so now I called a managed function and gave this function a native c++ function. 
Let's look into the managed code:

```
// This won't work
// typedef std::tr1::function<void __stdcall ()>* callback_function;
typedef std::tr1::function<void()>* callback_function;

callback_function m_nativCallback;

void ::SomeManagedFunction(callback_function callback)
{
  m_nativCallback = callback;
  // Does some stuff that triggers SomeManagedCallback
}

void ::SomeManagedCallback(IAsyncResult^ ar)
{
  (*m_nativCallback)();
}
```

Now, if I debug this, I get a `An unhandled exception of type System.AccessViolationException occurred in .dll  Additional information: An attempt was made to read or write in the protected memory. This is an indication that other memory is corrupted.` error message.

Can it be, that something is wrong with the calling convention?

Thanks

Comment: How do you use `void ::SomeManagedFunction(callback_function callback)` in your code? What do you pass as the `callback`?

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski I pass `::CallbackFunction(void)` as the callback. I use `::SomeManagedFunction` when a user is pressing a context-menu button. SomeManagedFunction then executes a function and needs to set a callback so I know when the called function is done.

Answer (score 0):

The native part was set up wrong:

```
void ::SomeNativeFunction(void)
{
  m_callback = std::tr1::bind(&::CallbackFunction, m_Tcy); // save in m_callback | m_Tcy is the class where CallbackFunction exists
  //this won't work
  m_Tcy->SomeManagedFunction(m_callback);
}
```

This worked for me:

```
void ::SomeNativeFunction(void)
    {
      m_callback = std::tr1::bind(&::CallbackFunction, m_Tcy); // save in m_callback | m_Tcy is the class where CallbackFunction exists
      //this works, even tho the debugger dies on me when I try to debug this
      m_Tcy->SomeManagedFunction(&m_callback);
    }
```

The callback stuff works, but still getting a error in the native main though:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00007ffb2b59dd60 in *.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation at location 0x00007ffb2b59dd60.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007ffb2b59dd60 in *.exe: 0xC000041D: Exception during a user callback.
```

Also, my visual studio 2010 crashes when debugging the callback (in my C++/CLI wrapper). If I wait long enough, it throws the following exceptions:

```
Access violation reading location 0xfffffffffffffff8.
```

Comment: How do you define `m_Tcy`in your native class?

Comment: `m_tcy` is a shared pointer of a native class from my C++/CLI dll. `m_tcy`contains the functions from the .NET side that I need to access from native C++.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a type of the `m_tcy` is native class, not managed, right? I thought `m_tcy` is a reference to managed type.

Comment: It's a bit complicated. `m_tcy` is of course a native (C++/CLI) class, otherwise I wouldn't be able to use it inside my native app. But `m_tcy` contains a managed object (casual wrapping). So calling `m_tcy` 's `SomeManagedFunction` means, that `m_tcy` uses its managed object to execute the function.

Comment: Could you present that native class code? Otherwise it is hard to estimate what is the problem here. My guess is that garbage collector moves or delete your managed content during runtime.

Comment: It seems like the Callback function is running on another thread then the main thread. And I am doing UI stuff inside the callback function. Is this the possible cause of my errors?

Comment: Do you use WinForms? If yes, try to use [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls)

Comment: I know about Invoke, thanks @SlawomirOrlowski. But as I said, my app is pure native c++. Seems like my guess is correct. If I fire an event, inside my callback function, which gets handled on the main thread, my approach works fine.